# Understanding input and output size for Conv2d

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I'm learning image classification using PyTorch (using CIFAR-10 dataset) [following this link](http://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/cifar10_tutorial.html#sphx-glr-beginner-blitz-cifar10-tutorial-py).

I'm trying to understand the input & output parameters for the given `Conv2d` code:

```
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 6, 5)
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(6, 16, 5)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(16 * 5 * 5, 120)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(120, 84)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(84, 10)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv1(x)))
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv2(x)))
        x = x.view(-1, 16 * 5 * 5)
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc3(x)
        return x

net = Net()
```

My `conv2d()` understanding (Please correct if I am wrong/missing anything):

- since image has 3 channels that's why first parameter is `3`.
  `6` is no of filters (randomly chosen)
- `5` is kernel size (5, 5) (randomly chosen)
- likewise we create next layer (previous layer output is input of this layer)
- Now creating a fully connected layer using `linear` function:
  self.fc1 = nn.Linear(16 * 5 * 5, 120)

`16 * 5 * 5`: here `16` is the output of last conv2d layer, But what is `5 * 5` in this?.

Is this kernel size ? or something else? How to know we need to multiply by `5*5 or 4*4 or 3*3.....`

I researched & got to know that since image size is `32*32`, applying max pool(2) 2 times, so image size would be 32 -> 16 -> 8, so we should multiply it by `last_ouput_size * 8 * 8` But in this link its `5*5`.

Could anyone please explain?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These are the dimensions of the image size itself (i.e. Height x Width).

### Unpadded convolutions

Unless you pad your image with zeros, a convolutional filter will shrink the size of your output image by `filter_size - 1` across the height and width:

| [image] | [image] |
| --- | --- |
| 3-filter takes a 5x5 image to a (5-(3-1) x 5-(3-1)) image | Zero padding preserves image dimensions |

You can add padding in Pytorch by setting `Conv2d(padding=...)`.

### Chain of transformations

Since it has gone through:

| Layer | Shape Transformation |
| --- | --- |
| one conv layer (without padding) | `(h, w) -> (h-4, w-4)` |
| a MaxPool | `-> ((h-4)//2, (w-4)//2)` |
| another conv layer (without padding) | `-> ((h-8)//2, (w-8)//2)` |
| another MaxPool | `-> ((h-8)//4, (w-8)//4)` |
| a Flatten | `-> ((h-8)//4 * (w-8)//4)` |

We go from the original image size of `(32,32)` to `(28,28)` to `(14,14)` to `(10,10)` to `(5,5)` to `(5x5)`.

---

To visualise this you can use the `torchsummary` package:

```
from torchsummary import summary

input_shape = (3,32,32)
summary(Net(), input_shape)
```

```py
----------------------------------------------------------------
        Layer (type)               Output Shape         Param #
================================================================
            Conv2d-1            [-1, 6, 28, 28]             456
         MaxPool2d-2            [-1, 6, 14, 14]               0
            Conv2d-3           [-1, 16, 10, 10]           2,416
         MaxPool2d-4             [-1, 16, 5, 5]               0
            Linear-5                  [-1, 120]          48,120
            Linear-6                   [-1, 84]          10,164
            Linear-7                   [-1, 10]             850
================================================================
```